# create a masking layer in deep learning generative model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have created a generative model, which trains on padded sequences with a length of 129. I have tried to add a masking layer, but I get the following error message:

```
input_length" is 129, but received input has shape (None, 129, 7905).
```

`vocab_size = 7905`

`seq_length_sent = 129`

Here is the model:

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape=(seq_length_sent, vocab_size)))
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=seq_length_sent)) 
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')) 
print(model.summary())
```

The input are padded sequences, that have been tokenized so each word is represented by an integer. The output word is one-hot encoded by the following code:

```
X, y = sequences_sent[:,:-1], sequences_sent[:,-1] 
y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)
```

This is the first time, I'm making such a model, so I'm not sure whether the approach is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in where you define your input shape. I assume the input to your model are tokenized padded sequences. Therefore, the input should not be of shape of the `seq_length_sent*vocab_size`, but only of shape `seq_length_sent`

So to fix your issue just replace:

`model.add(Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape=(seq_length_sent, vocab_size)))`

with

`model.add(Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape=(seq_length_sent,)))`

Comment: Thank you. I replaced the masking layer with your code and the model runs, but when I look at the summary for the masking layer, the output shape is (none,129) and param is 0. I'm not sure, but I thought that parameters were the total input to the layer. Is that correctly understood?

Comment: The Masking layer is acting as your input layer here and therefore has 0 trainable/nontrainable params. This simply means there are 0 weights connected to the input of the masking layer because it only receives the actual input.
Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561306/understanding-model-summary-keras?rq=1 here you can see that the input layer also has 0 params despite receiving a shape (150, 150, 3) tensor

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you. Can I ask you one more question? I have divided the text into tokenized padded sequences, so that every input is an entirely new sequence. I was originally working on a tutorial which just let the text flow together across sentences. Then making the sequences I iterated over the list of tokens from token 51 onwards and taking the prior 50 tokens as a sequence, then repeating this process to the end of the list of tokens. So that all except one word was contained in the following sequence. I'm unsure whether I should do something similar in this case?

Comment: That sounds about right, although your code suggests your sequences are of length 129 and not 50. Either way, I'd look at this simple tutorial https://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/ at least for the preprocessing bit

Comment: I actually used that exact tutorial. What I'm in doubt about is how I how I should do now that I have divided the text into sequences according to sentences (some is 3 long and the longest is 129) and padded with extra zeros, so that all become the length of 129. Before two sequences would be like "the sky is blue" and the next "sky is blue today" and the next "is blue today and". Now that I have changed the approach, each sequence caries no information from the previous sequences.

Comment: Both approaches are valid depending on what you're trying to achieve. Second one will train much faster though as it generates less data. Feel free to approve the answer now if it helped you and wrap up or ask a separate question as we're getting pretty far off topic now

Answer (score 0):

The input are padded sequences, that have been tokenized so each word is represented by an integer. The output word is one-hot encoded by the following code:

```
X, y = sequences_sent[:,:-1], sequences_sent[:,-1] 
y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)
```

This is the first time, I'm making such a model, so I'm not sure whether the approach is right.

Answer (score -1):

The error comes from how you define your masking layer. If your input is padded sequences of words and each word is one hot encoded, then you have correctly defined your masking layer. However, if your input is padded sequences of words without one hot encoding then you have to define your masking layer as

`model.add(Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape=(seq_length_sent,)))`

instead of

`model.add(Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape=(seq_length_sent,vocab_size))`

Comment: this is the exact duplicate of the answer below

Comment: If you just look at the code yes. But if you look at the explanation, your assumes that input are padded sequences alone and does not consider the fact that OP might have forgot to do one hot encoding of the padded sequence. Infact my answer is more holistic than yours

Comment: The input are padded sequences, that have been tokenized so each word is represented by an integer. The output word is one-hot encoded by the following code: X, y = sequences_sent[:,:-1], sequences_sent[:,-1] #separate into input and output sequences
print(X) #input
print(y) #output
y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)

Comment: @Signe you need to update the question you asked if you want to add additional things to your original post